# Setting headless property in .net

Tags: .net, headless

In java you can set a "headless" flag to true to reconcile the differences between a headless server environment and your desktop development environment.

```
System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "true");
```

So whenever you try to do an operation not supported in a headless environment the VM throws an Exception

What are the settings or flags I can modify to simulate my application running in an IIS app pool instead of the local .NET VM?

Edit: to clarify my intentions, I am going to use code that calls System.Windows.Forms.dll, WindowsBase.dll etc and the openGL wrapper OpenTK that might instantiate a window.

Comment: The *compiler* complains? Wow.

Comment: I doubt it's the compiler that complains -- it's probably the runtime...

Comment: "that might instantiate a window" And you want it to throw? Are you sure you want to create a "headless" app that references WinForms or WPF? Can you share why?

Comment: Dont worry, it was never a question about winforms or wpf anyway, just to summarize the answer, to reconcile the differences between a "headless" .net vm and a normal one is in "Environment.UserInteractive" flag. Thanks Marc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> simulate my application running in an IIS app pool instead of the local .NET VM?

Well, the local VM won't be *miles* out (assuming you're hosting in *some* kind of web-server), but to be honest - why simulate? *Host* it in IIS; that is fine. To check for subtle server OS issues, I run a server OS in a VM and deploy / remote-debug etc to that.

---

To check at runtime, you might check `Environment.UserInteractive`; most service-based code will report false - where-as winforms etc will return true.

IMO, this is rarely an issue, though.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your code not to compile if you instantiate a window, simply don't reference `System.Windows.Forms.dll` (WinForms) nor `WindowsBase.dll` (WPF).